# Windows narrator not reading web page content properly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, accessibility, narrator

I have enabled windows narrator for a web page and its working properly in Internet Explorer whereas the same page is not being read properly by windows narrator if i open that page in Chrome. its simply saying tab tab whenever i do tab. What could be the reason being this behavior. I did check for missing html title attributes but there were none. Html being rendered is same for both browsers.

Comment: Do you have access to JAWS or VoiceOver on a Mac or iPad?  If not, I can try it out if you send me the url.  You can either post that hear or send me a PM.  I have both JAWS and VoiceOver.